# mapStateToProps doesn't provide a data from the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

And don't know how can *this.props.movies* be undefined while I have *initialState* declared as *[]* and then it must straightly go to render?

So there are files:

Reducer.js

```
import * as types from "./ActionTypes.js";

const initialState = { movies: [] };

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(state.movies);
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.GET_MOVIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        movies: action.value
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Movies.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import MovieItem from "./MovieItem";

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  movies: state.movies
});

class Movies extends Component {
  render() {
    let movieItems = this.props.movies.map(movie => {
      return <MovieItem movie={movie} />;
    });
    return <div className="Movies">{movieItems}</div>;
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Movies);
```

And even if I put if-statement like

```
if (this.props.movies){
...
}else return 1;
```

it never rerenders

Comment: do you have a single reducer file or using multiple reducers and combining them by `combineReducers`?

Comment: I have combineReducers with only single reducer file like that

`export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  reducer: reducer
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    movies: state.reducer.movies
});
```

Because your initial state is a object:

```
initialState = { movies: [] };
```

And you are using `combineReducers` like this:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ reducer: reducer });
```

Now all the `initialState` of that reducer will be accessible by `state.reducer.propertyName`.

**Note:** Instead of using `reducer`, better to use some intuitive name like `moviesReducer`. Later in future if you will add more reducers then it will help to identify the the data.